# If $f:(0,1)\times (0,1)\to \mathbb R$ is continuous and integrable, then so is $F(x)=\int_0^1 f(x,t)dt$

Tags: real-analysis, integration

Let $f:(0,1)\times (0,1)\to \mathbb R$ continuous, and $f(x,\cdot )\in L^1$ for all $x$. Prove or disprove that $$F(x):=\int_0^1 f(x,t)dt$$
is continuous on $(0,1)$.

So, if $f$ is extendable by continuity on $[0,1]\times [0,1]$, then $f$ is uniformly continuous, and I could solve the problem. But How can I do if $f$ is not extendable by continuity ?

So $$|F(x+h)-F(x)|\leq \int_0^1 |f(x+h,t)-f(t)|dt.$$
Let $\varepsilon >0$. Thereis $\delta >0$ s.t. $|(x,t)-(x+h,t)|<\delta \implies |f(x+h,t)-f(x,t)|$, but here, $\delta $ depend on $t$. Is there a way to avoid this problem ?

Answer (score 2):

The answer is negative.

Consider $\frac{2t+2x-1}{(2x-1)^2} I_{x+ t < \frac12}.$